# How to send file as a dime attachment using SOAP request in Perl?

Tags: perl, web-services, soap, wsdl

My WSDL has a SOAP action 'TransferFile' that takes a file as a DIME attachment and stores it on remote device file system. The Path to the desired location on the remote device where the file is to be transferred is a parameter for the SOAP action.

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
            -> proxy('http://'.$ipAddress.':$port',
                     cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new(ignore_discard => 1)
                    )
           -> uri('idws');

$soap->autotype(0);

my $ent = build MIME::Entity
    Type        => "file",
#   Encoding    => "base64",
    Path        => "$file_path",
    Filename    => "test_tr_files",
    Disposition => "attachment";

my $som_ent = $soap->parts([$ent]);

my $som_tf = $soap->TransferFile(SOAP::Data->name("RemotePath"=>"$rpath"));
```

**$som_tf->result** always return false and the file is not transferred to the device.

Using Trace and debug for SOAP::Lite module shows an error with  $soap->parts([$ent]). 
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

No luck even with SOAPui.

Is there a different Library that can be used for the same purpose or am I doing it wrong?

The soap connection is fine as other SOAP calls which do not require a dime attachment are running without any trouble.